# How can I show a sequence of numbers using a counter in Verilog

Tags: counter, verilog

For example a have to show 0 , 2 , 4 , 0 , 2 , 4 .. I use an output with 8 segments - less important .

```
 output reg [7:0] data
 always @ (*) begin             
 case                                
 1:data= 8'b00000011; //number 0                        
 2:data= 8'b00100101; //number 2                     
 3:data= 8'b10011001; //number 4 
 default:data=8'b00000011;
 endcase
 end
```

And the counter :

```
input clock,
input reset,
output [7:0] out
reg [31:0] counter;
always @ (posedge clock) begin
if(reset==1)  counter <= 0;
else counter <= counter + 1;
end
```

My question is can I increment the case value instead of counter ?
Like :

```
always @ (posedge clock) begin
if(reset==1)  case <= 1;
else case <= case + 1;
if(case==3) reset<=1;
end
```

If not then how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your case statement is wrong. It should select based on the counter value:

```
always @ (*) begin             
 case(counter)
  1: data= 8'b00000011; //number 0                        
  2: data= 8'b00100101; //number 2                     
  3: data= 8'b10011001; //number 4 
  default:data=8'b00000011;
 endcase
 end
```

Your counter should be:

```
always @ (posedge clock) begin
  if(reset==1 || counter == 3)  counter <= 1;
  else counter <= counter + 1;
end
```

Note that `case` is a keyword. You can't use it in an expression.

Comment: I tried this and the sequence shown is : default value , 0 , 2 , default value , 0 , 2 .. If I change the line `if(reset==1 || counter==3)` into `if(reset==1||counter==4)` the sequence is : default value , 0 , 2 , 4 , default value , 0 , 2 , 4 ... Also when reset is 1 the sequence begins with default value not with 0 . Any solutions ?

Comment: Did you use non-blocking assignment <= ? Can you post your code on edaplayground.com?

Also, notice that reset here is synchronous. When it is set to 1, it would not be observed until the posedge of the clock.

Comment: One way to debug your code is to write a `$display` in a separate always block: `if (data == 8'b00000011) $display ("%h", counter);` This will show you what is the value of the counter outside 1, 2, and 3.